# hg status list without status

Tags: mercurial

I have to get list of changed, added or removed files since last commit.
command: `hg status` gives me for example

```
M file_path
C other_file_path
```

I need:

```
file_path
other_file_path
```

Solution have to work in Unix & Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to list all of the files, you can simply add `-n` to the `hg status` command:

```
$ hg status
M modded.txt
A added.txt
R removed.txt
? unknown.txt

$ hg status -n
modded.txt
added.txt
removed.txt
unknown.txt
```

However, this will also list unknown files (those that are new, but have not been specifically added to the repository with a `hg add` command).  You can get around this by adding either `-q` (as Lazy Badger points out), or by using filesets (see `hg help filesets`) to specify all files that *aren't* unknown:

```
$ hg status -n -q
modded.txt
added.txt
removed.txt

$ hg status -n "set:!unknown()"
modded.txt
added.txt
removed.txt
```

You can specify which types of files are listed by combining the other options (`-a -r` for example will show added and removed files).  Alternatively you can do clever things with filesets: for example, only listing the names of files that are removed by using `"set:removed()"`

Comment: Instead of fileset, options of status have to be used

Comment: " Option -q/--quiet hides untracked (unknown and ignored) files unless
    explicitly requested with -u/--unknown or -i/--ignored." - `hg help status`

Comment: Indeed, I had forgotten about `-q` as I've been doing some stuff with filesets so that is what initially occurred to me... `-q` is a much simpler option :). I'll add that to the answer, but keep the filesets as I think it's a good thing to know about.